# Help and Tips needing for workout plan

Tags: workout-routines, abdominals, arms, goals

I am currently 15 years old. I am 6' tall and I weigh 157 pounds. I am not fat however I am not comfortable with my shirt off because of my unappealing, "skinny-fat" stomach and chest. My goal is to be proud of my body and comfortable with a shirt off by next summer. More specifically, Defined Upper body and core. My workout plan is geared towards slow, but steady progress. I am aiming towards small lifestyle changes and consistent exercise to reach my goal. So far I have made a simple plan open too tweaks as I go on. Here's my plan: I Bought a simple set of dumbells, and I am alternating between Upper body, and Lower Body workout days. For the workouts I do 4 sets of 10 Bicep curls, Tricep Extensions, Hammer curls, Tricep Kick backs, spyder curls, and finally push ups. On lower body days I do Weighted Squats, Weighted Crunches, Lunges, Halos, Goblet Squats, again 4 sets of 10 each side. Currently using two 15 pound dumbells but will increase weight as soon as I feel comfortable with the increase. I finish each workout with a protein bar. On top of the daily workout, I fill my day with plenty of cardio, and trying to make better dietary choices. Can anyone tell me if I will reach my goal with this program? if not, what changes can be made?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your plan doesn't have any back work, it's important to do back work or you'll get muscle imbalances and you'll injure yourself, it's also very important for a good posture. If you're just starting out I recommend starting with a routine that was made by people who know their stuff instead putting something together yourself. If you want to workout at home, I would recommend the reddit bodyweightfitness Recommended Routine. It's mainly bodyweight, your dumbells can be used for the squats. Lots of people have used it, it's been refined over time by a community, there's a friendly space to ask any question you have, it has a good warmup, and it will teach you cool shit like handstands, planches, L-sits, etc

https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/kb/recommended_routine

Demonstrated there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpobvFPR6hQ

Once you have some experience, you can make the modifications you want or switch to something else

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing lots of cardio, you should do interval running over distances ranging between 100 and 800 metres. If you run hard and give yourself a little bit of rest between the runs, your body will release a lot of testosterone which will help you gain muscle.

Comment: Care to validate the claim: "If you run hard and give yourself a little bit of rest between the runs, your body will release a lot of testosterone"?

Comment: Sorry, I have read it a while a go so I can't remember the exact source. But there are loads of studies that have been done which link high intensity exercise to testosterone release.

Answer (score 0):

*Pancake* already has made a good point. 
I would add that the nutrition is at least as much important as the workout itself, I think it's even more important. Eat clean, much protein and lots of vegetables.

I would also recommend you to track and review your progress. Write down your sets and reps, track your weight and make photos of your body (no ad: the app MyFitnessPal has a cool feature for this). So when you notice there are not the wanted results you can look what may be the problem and change things.

I know it's hard to change all these things. 
I would suggest you to break everything into little sub-goals and reach them one after another, it's likely not going to work if you change all at once. Focus on the basics first and slowly add new things. So take your time and don't worry if something don't work at first or second try, you'll learn and do it better.

I wish you good luck with your goals!